# how to choose what view will be on top in android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-inflate

I'm trying to add a View on top of another one.

First I am setting a view via the xml and then I want to add the second one programatically.
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

```
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
  drawView = new DrawView(this);
  drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
  Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(10, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
  Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
  drawView.draw(canvas);
  drawView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(800, 0, 0.18f));
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)drawView.getLayoutParams();
  params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, -130);
  drawView.setLayoutParams(params);
  ll.addView(drawView, 2);
```

}

My problem is that the xml is on top of the view that I am trying to add.

How can I make the second view on top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the view's [`bringToFront`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#bringToFront()) method:

```
drawView.bringToFront();
```

Comment: when i do this it make the view disappear

Comment: Strange. Can you try to add the view as the first? `ll.addView(drawView, 0)`

Comment: I think the real problem is the choice of layout, as @Luksprog pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

`LinearLayout` is a layout that arranges its children one after the other vertical or horizontal. If you want to stack views one on top of the other then use a layout that allows that, like a `RelativeLayout`, instead of the `LinearLayout`.

Comment: shouldnt margin  do the trick too? or thats what hapens whan you use margin in a linear layout?

Comment: @roiberg I don't know your exact layout to see what is happening but I don't think the margins will work. And even if it works you'll probably don't want to do use margins if you want to make your app look decent on all phone screens and not just the current one.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stack views one over another you should use Relative Layout. So in your case replace "layout" with Relative layout, in java code you can do something like below.

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams baseLayoutParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    baseLayout.setLayoutParams(baseLayoutParam);
    DrawView drawView = new DrawView(context);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, (int) (250 * Utility.getDip(context)));
    rLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT); // Adjust accordingly to your requirement
    drawView.setLayoutParams(rLayoutParams);ll.addView(drawView);
```